# Create outlook task from shared inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, task

I need to create outlook task from shared inbox. So far when below code runs, task is created with owner of shared inbox as I want, but when saved I get "You must be in a public folder to change the owner field of a task" error and owner is changed back to me.

I couldn't find solution or it might have been beyond my understanding. I appreciate the help. Thanks!

```
If task = "YES" Then
   user_task = "GR"
   Const olTaskItem = 3
   Dim OlApp As Object
   Dim OlTask As Object

   Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set OlTask = OlApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

   With OlTask
       '.Assign
       '.Recipients.Add "shared@inbox.com" 'workaround to assign task for another owner, but does not show .BCC so not suitable solution.
       .Owner = "shared@inbox.com" ' does not work. changes back to my user
       .Subject = material_full_email & " spp "
       .StartDate = Date
       .DueDate = Date + 7
       .Status = 1                 '0=not started, 1=in progress, 2=complete, 3=waiting,
                                   '4=deferred
       .Importance = 1             '0=low, 1=normal, 2=high
       .ReminderSet = False
       '.ReminderTime = dtReminderDate
       '.Categories = "Business" 'use any of the predefined Categorys or create your own
       .Body = Date & " " & user_task & ":" & " RFQ sent: " & Supplier1 & " / " & Supplier2 & " / " & Supplier3 & " / " & Supplier4
       '.Save   'use .Display if you wish the user to see the task form and make
       .Display       'them perform the save
   End With
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItem`, call  `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` passing the name or address of the owner of the mailbox, call `Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder`, then use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.

**UPDATE**:

```
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set NS = olApp.getNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
ste Recip = NS.CreateRecipient("someuser@company.demo")
set SharedFolder = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFoldersTasks)
Set OlTask = SharedFolder.Items.Add
...
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I am not so experienced in vba. Do you think you could give a snippet of code adaptef with your suggestion? When i try to do it, i just cant make it work. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi. I tried this morning to run the code, but couldn't make it work. It runs, but does not generate any task. Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I get true on resolving the inbox, however I can't create a bloody task to save my life :(. Read countless topics which all seem to advice same thing, but can't make it work and have no idea why.

Comment: I got it working. I am marking your comment as an answer as it got me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get below code work. I believe biggest problem was MS Outlook library not ticked in references.

```
If task = "YES" Then
   user_task = "GR"
   Const olTaskItem = 3
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim ns As Object
   Dim OlTask As Object
   Dim SharedFolder As Object
   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   ns.Logon
   Set Recip = ns.CreateRecipient("inboxname")
   Set SharedFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFolderTasks)
   Set OlTask = SharedFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Task")
   'Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   'Set OlTask = OLApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

   With OlTask
       '.Assign
       '.Recipients.Add "shared@inbox.com"
       '.Owner = "shared@inbox.com" ' not needed
       .Subject = material_full_email & " spp "
       .StartDate = Date
       .DueDate = Date + 7
       .Status = 1                 '0=not started, 1=in progress, 2=complete, 3=waiting,
                                   '4=deferred
       .Importance = 1             '0=low, 1=normal, 2=high
       .ReminderSet = False
       '.ReminderTime = dtReminderDate
       '.Categories = "Business" 'use any of the predefined Categorys or create your own
       .Body = Date & " " & user_task & ":" & " RFQ sent to suppliers: " & Supplier1 & " / " & Supplier2 & " / " & Supplier3 & " / " & Supplier4
       '.Save   'use .Display if you wish the user to see the task form and make
       .Display       'them perform the save
   End With
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have something more simple for this:

```
Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem
' Set the Application object
Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
Set NewTask = objOLApp.Session.Folders.Item(x).Items.Add(olTaskItem)
With NewTask...
```

Where 'x' stands for your shared inbox ID (for me this is 5). You can use `MsgBox Prompt:=objOLApp.Session.Folders.Item(x)` to check. It should return shared inbox adress on correct ID (adress@server.com).