# Post appointment to shared Outlook calendar from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've seen a ton of examples for this but none are consistent and trying them, none seem to work. The below code works great but puts it on my personal calendar not the shared one i'm trying to post to. Thanks for any help

```
Sub CreateEmailFromExcel1()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
    Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
         
    With OutMeet
        .Subject = "Stage 1 for " & Range("f2") & " - " & Range("b2")
        .Start = Range("b75") & " " & Range("L72")
        .Duration = 30
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
        .Body = "This is the stage one for " & Range("f2") & " - " & Range("b2") & ". The ticket is " & Range("c72") & ". Please make sure it is approved before running. " & vbLf & "Step 1: Please run disable script " & Range("c73") & vbLf & "Step 2: Please run stage 1 for pools" & Range("h24") & ", " & Range("L24")
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Tried a bunch of code examples from other posts. I either got an error stating I was missing objects or the appointment was still on my personal one.

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but, apparently, you shouldn't use `Application.CreateItem` (which creates the item in the default folder), but rather first find a reference to the target folder and then use `Items.Add` on that folder. Does the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29038253/87698) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Outlook appointment in shared calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490188/create-outlook-appointment-in-shared-calendar)

Comment: Pick one of the "code examples from other posts". Ask about that code. State the error and the line that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a script that works. Wanted to post here incase some one else came across this and wanted to know how I fixed it. It comes from here but I simplified it https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/creating-an-outlook-appointment-in-a-shared-calendar.1074487/

```
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim outSharedName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim outCalendarFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim outAppointment As AppointmentItem
    Dim SharedMailboxEmail As String
    
    SharedMailboxEmail = "sharedEmail@youraddress.com"  'CHANGE THIS
    
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outNameSpace = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outSharedName = outNameSpace.CreateRecipient(SharedMailboxEmail)
    Set outCalendarFolder = outNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outSharedName, olFolderCalendar)
    Set outAppointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    With outAppointment
    End With
```

Then put your desired subject, body, duration, and all that in between the with's.